How to install ncurses package for ARM64 machine on x86 machine during cross compilation?
Error: cannot find -lncurses
How to fix this error?
I have executed these set of commands.
sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libncurses5:arm64 libncursesw5:arm64
sudo apt install libncurses5-dev:arm64 libncursesw5-dev:arm64

After execution, I am getting this error.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libncurses-dev:arm64 : Depends: libncurses6:arm64 (= 6.2-0ubuntu2.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libncursesw6:arm64 (= 6.2-0ubuntu2.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libc6-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libc-dev:arm64
 libtinfo6:arm64 : Depends: libc6:arm64 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


Please [edit] your question and copy&paste all text as text instead of showing a screenshot, and add details to the question: How did you install the cross compiler? If it is not an Ubuntu package, how does it know where to find the libraries? I suggest to install packages using a tool that can resolve dependencies and propose solutions, e.g. aptitude.

Debian (and derived stuff) don't provide packages except those tools needed to do cross-compiles.  If you want ncurses in a cross-environment in Ubuntu, you'll have to configure and compile it yourself.
